# Flutter localization error: No instance of S present in the widget tree. Did you add S.delegate in localizationsDelegates?

Tags: flutter, localization

Flutter error: No instance of S present in the widget tree. Did you add S.delegate in localizationsDelegates?

I am trying to access the localization class S in another widget from the main home widget which is MyApp() but it give me this error every time I run the program.

However the S class is working fine in the main.dart file but not in any other screen.

I hope someone can help

I tried many solutions like flutter clean and closing the IDE and other solutions but they all didn't work